# Fit logistic regression with linear constraints on coefficients in R

Tags: r, logistic, optimization, constraint

This is (I think) a routine question, but I haven't seen an answer here. In the past I had to fit logistic regression models with linear constraints on the coefficients, in the case when some of the predictors were categorical.  Until now I've been using `glmnet`, which by the way only allows bound constraints ($a_i\leq\beta_i\leq b_i $). However, apart from the limitation on the type of constraints, I find it annoying to be forced to use `glmnet` matrix/column specification for data, instead than a more expressive `formula` as done in `glm`. Also, most of the times I only needed to fit an unregularized logistic regression model ($\lambda=0$). However, `glmnet` help warns against fitting the model for a single value of $\lambda$. Thus I had to fit a sequence of models, parameterized by a sequence of $\lambda$, and then extract the model corresponding to $\lambda=0$. It gets boring the $n-$th time you have to do it.

For all these reasons I'm looking into other solutions to fit unregularized logistic regression models, with linear constraints on the coefficients. One could of course derive the objective function for logistic regression (as done [here](http://openclassroom.stanford.edu/MainFolder/DocumentPage.php?course=MachineLearning&doc=exercises/ex5/ex5.html)) and then use an optimizer in R which supports convex optimization problems and linear constraints (any suggestions?). However, this is complicated and I'm not sure how I would setup the optimization to take into account the categorical predictors. Is there a simpler way to achieve my goal? If not, can you show me in detail how to do this with optimization ?

Comment: Does "linear constraints" means that one of the coefficients can be expressed as a linear combination of the others? Would the approach outlined by Glen_b [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/85912/82898) (combining the predictors to satisfy the constrain) help?

Comment: Could you just fit a Bayesian model & specify the prior to have 0 density in a given region?

Comment: @juice not necessarily. That would indeed be the case for linear *equality* constraints: in that case, some coefficients may be written as linear combinationsystem of the others. But I was thinking if linear *inequality* constraints. The coefficient vector $\mathbf{\beta}= (\beta_1,\dots,\beta_p)$ must satisfy $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{\beta}-\mathbf{b}\leq 0$, where $\mathbf{A}$  is  $d\times p$, with $d$ the number of such constraints, and $p$ the number of coefficients in the model.

Comment: @gung good idea, I had also thought of Bayesian logistic regression, but: 1. the only R package I know of which allows non-normal priors for logistic regression  is `brms`, and frankly installing Stan to solve this problem sounds like using a cannon to kill a fly. 2. Bayes gives me a posterior distribution. I only need point estimates for the coefficients (the model goal is prediction, not inference). Of course I can summarise  $p (\theta|y)$ by mean, mode, etc. but again, I was thinking of a simple solution. Anyway, I'd accept a Bayesian answer, if there is no simpler way.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not clear to me. But if you want to use formula instead of matrix input. You can use `caret` pacakge, which provide universal interface to many packages including `glmnet`. Or you can use `model.matrix` to convert formula to matrix form.

If you want to fit a logistic regression with $\lambda=0$, you can directly use traditional `glm`. If you want to manually implement it, my answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/239503/what-is-the-equivalent-in-r-of-scikit-learns-logisticregression-with-penalty/239506#239506) has the code to to calculate the objective function and gradient of logistic loss and use BFGS to optimize.

---

For the revised question: projected gradient descent may work well, since the "box constraints" is easy to solve. My answer here gives some details on projected gradient descent. (I believe projected gradient descent is used by `glmnet`).

[Solving constrained optimization problem: projected gradient vs. dual?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/272578/solving-constrained-optimization-problem-projected-gradient-vs-dual/272928#272928)

Additional reference for projected gradient descent, book from the author of glmnet: [Statistical Learning with Sparsity](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/StatLearnSparsity_files/SLS.pdf) page 120

Comment: you're right, it's late and my brain is not working properly :) so the question was unclear.  Please have a look at my edits and let me know if it's more comprehensible now.

Comment: @DeltaIV the revision looks much better! I would further suggest to remove the details on `glmnet`, just say, how to do logistic regression with constrain on coefficient. In addition, if you study `model.matrix` and [this link](http://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/library/r-library-contrast-coding-systems-for-categorical-variables/) it will answer your question about how to deal with discrete variables. (which is a separate question may cause further confusion to the original question)

Comment: `nls` is not applicable here. The objective function of logistic regression is not a sum of squares, thus constrained nonlinear least squares isn't helpful (constrained  linear least squares, even less).

Comment: On the contrary , projected gradient descent sounds nice...your link states that a closed form solution is available for linear constraints. Can you show the closed form solution? Note that I'm talking about *inequality* constraints. If linear constraints are too complicated, even the closed form solution for box constraints would be ok.

Comment: @DeltaIV sorry my mistake, I thought it is `nlm` not `nls`. I revised my answer.

Comment: sorry to insist, but in order to accept the answer I need a workflow illustrating the projected gradient descent algorithm for my case (box constraints), or at least the name of an R package which implements it. I tried reading the Hastie's et al. book (page 102) but the treatment is very technical and concerned with regularization (which I don't need). This "soft threshold" is only illustrated for proximal gradient descent (which is more complex than projected gradient descent) and I don't understand how to apply it in practice to my problem.